# synonym and acronym search in elasticsearch with index data

Tags: elasticsearch

I will create index test_synonym and add data like below:

```
POST /test_synonym/_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_synonym","_id":"1"}}
{"name":"test one two","description":"test numbers","synonyms": ["tot, number"]}
{"index":{"_index":"test_synonym","_id":"1"}}
{"name":"test coding","description":"test coding","synonyms": ["tc, program"]}
```

Now while creating index I need to create the analyzer so I am unable to use the above data for synonym search all example shows use separate synonym.txt or synonym.csv. Instead of separate path how to use  index test_synonym data value. If you see above data in each record I have added attribute called synonyms. How I can use that attribute instead of separate text or csv file.

Answer (score 0):

**Great news!** You don't need to have any synonym table because the synonym data is already in the data itself :)

### So just query both `name` the `synonyms` field.

```
POST /test_synonym/_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_synonym","_id":"1"}}
{"name":"test one two","description":"test numbers","synonyms": ["tot, number"]}
{"index":{"_index":"test_synonym","_id":"2"}}
{"name":"test coding","description":"test coding","synonyms": ["tc, program"]}
```

#to understand how it analyze the data in default

```
POST _analyze
{
  "text": ["tot, number"]
}
```

#the query

```
GET test_synonym/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "tot",
      "fields": ["name", "synonyms"]
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you..Can you provide me while creating index test_synonym how to define analyzer and mapping for the above?

Comment: I used dynamic mapping called ECS.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs/current/ecs-field-reference.html